# Selectively remove deprecated rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe containing data that looks like below.

```
p,g,a,s,v
15,196,1399,16,5
15,196,948,5,1
15,196,1894,5,1
15,196,1616,5,1
15,196,1742,3,1
15,196,1742,4,4
15,196,1742,5,1
15,195,732,9,2
15,195,1765,11,7
15,196,1815,9,1
15,196,1399,11,8
15,196,1958,0,1
15,195,767,9,1
15,195,1765,11,8
15,195,886,9,1
15,195,1765,11,9
15,196,1958,5,1
15,196,1697,1,1
15,196,1697,4,1
```

Given multiple entries that have the same `p`, `g`, `a`, and `s`, I need to drop all but the one with the highest `v`. The reason is that the original source of this data is a kind of event log, and each line corresponds to a "new total". If it matters, the source data is ordered by time and includes a timestamp index, which I removed for brevity. The entry with the latest date would be the same as the entry with the highest `v`, as `v` only increases.

Pulling an example out of the above data, given this:

```
p,g,a,s,v
15,195,1765,11,7
15,195,1765,11,8
15,195,1765,11,9
```

I need to drop the first two rows and keep the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly I think you want the following, this performs a `groupby` on your cols of interest and then takes the `max` value of column 'v' and we then call `reset_index`:

```
In [103]:
df.groupby(['p', 'g', 'a',  's'])['v'].max().reset_index()

Out[103]:
     p    g     a   s  v
0   15  195   732   9  2
1   15  195   767   9  1
2   15  195   886   9  1
3   15  195  1765  11  9
4   15  196   948   5  1
5   15  196  1399  11  8
6   15  196  1399  16  5
7   15  196  1616   5  1
8   15  196  1697   1  1
9   15  196  1697   4  1
10  15  196  1742   3  1
11  15  196  1742   4  4
12  15  196  1742   5  1
13  15  196  1815   9  1
14  15  196  1894   5  1
15  15  196  1958   0  1
16  15  196  1958   5  1
```

Comment: This is precisely what I need. Thank you.